# Error in creating ExpandableListView with HashMap<String,List<String>>

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to create one simple ExpandableListView in android application.

Here is code that prepares data for ExpandableListView.I used for loop here because in my application this data is coming at run time so i am unable to recognize how long it will be.

```
header = new ArrayList<String>();
child = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

header.add("Top 250");
header.add("Now Showing");
header.add("Coming Soon");

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        List<String> Map = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map.add("Hello:" + i);
        child.put(header.get(i), Map);
}
```

And to fill the ExpandableListView i created custom adapter here is the code.

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    String headerData = this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);

    List<String> listData = this._listDataChild.get(headerData);

    return listData.get(childPosition);

}
```

when i am trying to run this app Header in the ExpandableListView appears perfect but when i click on particular header the application fails.

here is the logcat.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)

com.kamani.expandablelistdemo.MyCustomAdpater.getChild(MyCustomAdpater.java:36)

com.kamani.expandablelistdemo.MyCustomAdpater.getChildView(MyCustomAdpater.java:51)

android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
```

**I know that i am getting error in getChild() method in returning data it says IndexOutOfBoundsException but unable to understand how to make it correct so that it display one one Sting in one Header?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The getChildrenCount() method in adapter returns invalid value.**

Invalid value means the value may be greater then actual size or smaller then actual size.

It works first on getChildernCount() and then on getChild() method.

In my code i forgot to correct the code in getChilderCount() method.